# Specific word only with CONTAINS, FREETEXT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I search for a specific word only in full text indexed fields ?

I know I could just do "where field='word'" but I would rather have the search form as generic as possible and throw the search term to the CONTAINS, FREETEXT functions.

Seems there should be a word boundary or end of phrase character that could be used but there doesn't seem to be one.

I'm using MS SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Contains or FreeText, you must have a full-text index on the column(s) in question. Assuming you do, then you can force a search for a specific word by enclosing in double-quotes:

```
Select ..
From Table
Where Contains( SomeCol, '"word"')
```

[CONTAINS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187787%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

**Update**

If what you seek is to return results where the contents is only and exactly your search term, then the only way to do that is to use `=` or `Like` without a wildcard. I.e., there is no means to search on an exact match of the entire contents using the full-text search predicates. Thus, you must use:

```
Select ..
From Table
Where SomeCol = 'word'

Select ..
From Table
Where SomeCol Like 'word'
```

Comment: But that returns everything containing the word, not results only containing that word.

Comment: @User632607 - Huh? It returns everything that contains that specific word as opposed to parts of that word.

Comment: @User632607 - Is it that you are looking for results where the entire contents is only and exactly the word you pass?

Comment: I want a way to only get results exactly matching that word while still using contains or freetext. If there was something like regexp baked in to this it would be ^word$

Comment: @user632607 - There is no means to do that outside of an extended stored procedure or custom CLR function where you have it dynamically determine whether to use the fulltext predicates or just match using an equals sign.

Comment: @user632607 - Similarly, the only way to get full regex support is through a CLR function or extended stored proc.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm not allowed to vote up apparently but thank you for your time.